# Node issues installing Sails package with cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin, sails.js

I'm trying to install a package globally, I updated my node.js installation quite recently and I didn't encounter that issue before in node 0.10.

```
$ npm install sails -g
|
> sails@0.11.0 preinstall C:\Users\Vado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails
> node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

'node' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Logiciels installés\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Logiciels install
és\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sails" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sails@0.11.0 preinstall: `node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sails@0.11.0 preinstall script 'node ./lib/preinstall_npm
check.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sails package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sails
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\cygwin64\home\Vado\npm-debug.log
```

What's weird is that if I try to install `lodash` globally, it does work.

```
$ node --version
v0.12.3
```

**Note that this happens only from the cygwin console**, if I use my windows shell it works fine.

Any idea where the problem's coming from and how to fix it? I definitely *can run `node` from any shell* (cygwin/windows) so I don't get it.

I doubt it will be usefull, but here is the npm-debug.log: http://pastebin.com/v6zPWFN2

Comment: were you able to install sails

Comment: I was able to install sails 0.10 at the time yes, but now I can't anymore with sails 0.11. I may also be due to the fact that I've upgraded node from 0.10 to 0.12 as well, I have to use my windows shell to do so, boring but haven't found a better solution. It happens with a lot of other modules, so I guess it's related to node.